# Replace regex occurrences

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have an input string:

```
"hello [you], this is [me]"
```

I have a function which maps a string to a string (hardcoded for the sake of simplicity):

```
public String map(final String input) {
    if ("you".equals(input)) {
        return "SO";
    } else if ("me".equals(input)) {
        return "Kate";
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the most convenient way to replace each `[(.*)?]` occurrence by its respective mapping (given by calling the `map` function)?

If I am correct, you cannot use `String.replaceAll()` here, since we don't know the replacement in advance.

Comment: You should use a `java.util.Map<String, String>` instead of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the expression that you have is greedy. A proper expression to match a token in square brackets is `\[([^\]]*)\]` (backslashes need to be doubled for Java), because it avoids going past the closing square bracket<sup>*</sup>. I added a *capturing group* to access the content inside square brackets as `group(1)`.

Here is a way to do what you need:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer bufStr = new StringBuffer();
boolean flag = false;
while ((flag = m.find())) {
    String toReplace = m.group(1);
    m.appendReplacement(bufStr, map(toReplace));
}
m.appendTail(bufStr);
String result = bufStr.toString();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/mPjqA6)

<sup>*</sup> You can use `[.*?]`, too, but this reluctant expression may cause backtracking.

Comment: you mean `Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]*]\\]");`, otherwise your pattern will mach `"hello [you"`

Comment: @ericbn Thanks! I caught that error when working on my demo, so now it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I did not really understand the appendReplacement function. Now I do!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
String line = "hello [you], this is [me]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    // m.group(1) contains the text inside [] 
    // line.replace(m.group(1), yourMap.get(m.group(1)));
    // use StringBuilder to build the new string
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not really answer the complete question. Once an occurence is found (with `m.group(1)`), how can I replace it in the original input by its mapping?

Comment: Strings are immutable :) `line.replace` will not affect line.

Comment: By calling `replace`, aren't you scanning through the input string for a second time?

Comment: @KateDeens why is it a problem?

Comment: It seems odd to search for something (with the mather), find it, and then search again (with the replace function).

Comment: @KateDeens indeed, that's what the other answer suggests too. Nothing wrong with this approach.